# Виды переменных

Tags: java, классы, переменные, класс

1. Если переменная объявлена в теле класса и является static - значит это 
   переменная класса
2. Если переменная объявлена в теле класса и не является static - то это переменная объекта класса
3. Если переменная объявлена в теле метода - то это локальная переменная

Теперь вопрос:

Как называется переменная которая находится в `{}` и как называется переменная в `static{}`? Оба, в смысле `{}` и `static{}` находятся в теле класса.

Вот, к примеру:

```
abstract class AnyName{
    {int k;}
    static{int k;}
}
```

Дополнительно: не разрешается объявлять переменные в таких скобках ключевым словом `static`.

Comment: это локальные переменные, в первом случае конструктора по умолчанию, во втором - блока статической инициализации

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, неинициализированные переменные компилятор просто выкинет из результирующего модуля. Поэтому стоит как минимум присвоить им хоть какие-то значения.

```
public class Example {
    static { int a = 1; }

    { int b = 2; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  }
}
```

Во-вторых, все инструкции из нестатического блока инициализации будут просто перенесены в конструктор по умолчанию, а инструкции из статического блока инициализации будут перенесены в специальный метод [`<clinit>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9.2). Так что переменная `a` станет локальной переменной конструктора по умолчанию, а переменная `b` локальной переменной метода `<clinit>`.

```
public class Example {
  public Example();           // Конструктор по умолчанию
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1    // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: iconst_2
       5: istore_1            // Переменная b
       6: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return

  static {};                  // Статический инициализатор
    Code:
       0: iconst_1 
       1: istore_0            // Переменная a
       2: return 
}
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ